# How to stop Scroll changed event from triggering on data binding (WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, scrollviewer

```
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
                    <GroupStyle>
                        <GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="GroupItem">
                                <Setter Property="Template">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="GroupItem">
                                            <Grid>
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                    <RowDefinition/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  FontWeight="Bold"  Foreground="{StaticResource Accent}" Text="{Binding Path=Name , StringFormat={}{0:D}}"  />
                                                <ItemsPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </ControlTemplate>
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Style>
                        </GroupStyle.ContainerStyle>
                    </GroupStyle>
                </ItemsControl.GroupStyle>
            </ItemsControl>
            <Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
                <Interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="ScrollChanged" >
                    <Presentation:InvokeDelegateCommandAction  Command="{Binding ChatScrollViewer_OnViewChange}" CommandParameter="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=InvokeParameter}" />
                </Interactivity:EventTrigger>
            </Interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
        </ScrollViewer>



private void ChatScrollViewer_OnViewChangeEvent(ScrollChangedEventArgs Event)
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = Event.OriginalSource as ScrollViewer;
        if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == 0)
        {

        }
    }
```

> When data binding take place scroll changed event is triggered . How check that this is a trigger from data binding and do nothing and when triggered manually do something

Comment: `Event.Handled = true;
            return;` inside your if-clause

Comment: Can you please add more detail

Comment: If I understand your question right, you want to stop the execution of any logic if their was no scrolling action. Your if-clause asks if there hasn't been any vertical offset. If so you can use `Event.Handled = true;
            return;` which will stop the event and exit the method.

Comment: Keeping you code in my view model in if wont serve my purpose .What i want i a condition in my if to check that data binding is  taking place and do nothing.
Like

Comment: private void ChatScrollViewer_OnViewChangeEvent(ScrollChangedEventArgs Event)
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = Event.OriginalSource as ScrollViewer;
        if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == 0)
        {
          if( !   when data binding  ){
           }
        }
    }

Comment: My Scroll changed triggers two times.One from data binding and when someone manually moves scroll up or down .I want to stop this event from  triggering or i can put a conditional check that tell me triggered even was from data binding

Comment: hope you have idea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the binding is updated, is it the ItemsSource of the scroll viewer?

Chances are the binding is adding or removing something, resulting in the scroll viewer changing the size of it's content. Take a look at [the scroll changed event args](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.scrollchangedeventargs(v=vs.110).aspx), there's lot of conditions that trigger this event.

You probably only want to check the event properties like:

**VerticalChange** - Gets a value that indicates the change in vertical offset of a ScrollViewer.

So try only performing your action when VerticalChange != 0. Or drop a debugger in there and see if there's any specific event types you want to ignore that only happen when binding changes, for example:

**ExtentHeightChange** - Gets a value that indicates the change in height of the ScrollViewerextent.

Might only be none-zero when the binding has updated, making the scroll bar bigger (but not changing the scroll position).

So something like this:

```
private void ChatScrollViewer_OnViewChangeEvent(ScrollChangedEventArgs Event)
{
    if (Event.VerticalChange != 0)
    {
        ScrollViewer scrollViewer = Event.OriginalSource as ScrollViewer;
        if (scrollViewer.VerticalOffset == 0)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks Joe .You answer was great. It solved the problem